# XSL : display text between two milestone, show milestone value elsewhere

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working with a XML file that must be TEI-compilant. The problem is about the pb (page break) milestone. It's not a new problem, but the existing solutions are so complicated and heavy that I was wondering if there was a more simple way in my case.

Let's have this XML file part :

```
<body>
<pb n="2"/><p>Some random text is put here</p><p>Another
paragraph starts here, and in the 
middle of it<pb n="3"/> a page break occurred.</p><pb n="4"/
<p>the next paragraph begins
on a new page</p>
<p>But in the next paragraph, after<pb n="5"/>another page break, something else
 happend : a note<note
 type=glossary">the note content</note> and so everything
 failing <pb n="6"/> because of this note.
```

I would like to transform the XML into this HTML :

```
<table>
<tr><td><p>Some random text is put here</p><p>Another paragraph starts here, and in the 
middle of it</p></td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td><p>a page break occurred.</p></td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td><p>the next par graph begins on a new page</p></td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td><p>But in the next paragraph, after</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td><p>another page break, something else happend : a note
<note type=glossary">the note content</note> and so everything's failing</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>because of this note.</td></tr>
```

It seems to me that it should be possible to achieve quite simply with a for-each-group. So, basically, I was trying something like that :

```
<xsl:stylesheet
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">



    <xsl:template match="/body">
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="descendant::*" group-starting-with="pb">
        <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="current-group()"/>
        </td><td><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/@n"/>
        </td></tr>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </table>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Obviously, it doesn't work… the result is :

```
<table><tr><td> Some random text is put here Another paragraph starts here, and in the
middle of it a page break occurred.</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td/><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>
the next paragraph begins on 
a new page</td><td>4</td></tr></table>
```

Am I going in a totally wrong direction ?

Many thanks for your help !
Christophe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not in wrong direction with for-each-group. Sometimes it is useful (for me) to make some "preprocessing" of input document and save it into variable for further transformation.

I have this xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="fn xs fo">
    <xsl:output method="html" />

    <!-- Make some "preprocess" - just to splip everything containing pb -->
    <xsl:variable name="preprocess">
        <!-- Only root element shouldn't be splitted -->
        <xsl:element name="{/node()[1]/name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/node()[1]/node() | @*" mode="preprocess"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*" mode="preprocess">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" mode="preprocess"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[pb]" mode="preprocess">
        <!-- I don't know if pb could be in another element than p - so do it more generic -->
        <xsl:variable name="nodeName" select="name()" />
        <xsl:element name="{$nodeName}">
            <!-- Have to account there could be more pb elements - working with 1st of them -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="pb[1]/preceding-sibling::node()" mode="preprocess" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:copy-of select="pb[1]" />
        <!-- I have to continue with the rest of element - I store it into another variable 
            an encapsulate it with the element of the same name. Then it is processing
            in standard way. -->
        <xsl:variable name="restOfElement">
            <xsl:element name="{$nodeName}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="pb[1]/following-sibling::node()" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$restOfElement" mode="preprocess" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Apply for-each-group on preprocessed value -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="$preprocess/body/descendant::*" group-starting-with="pb">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[position() &gt; 1]" />
                            </td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()/@n"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In first step I split all elements containing `<pb>`. The variable then looks like following

```
<body>
    <pb n="2"/>
    <p>Some random text is put here</p>
    <p>Another
paragraph starts here, and in the 
middle of it</p>
    <pb n="3"/>
    <p> a page break occurred.</p>
    <pb n="4"/>
    <p>the next paragraph begins
on a new page</p>
    <p>But in the next paragraph, after</p>
    <pb n="5"/>
    <p>another page break, something else
 happend : a note<note type="glossary">the note content</note> and so everything
 failing </p>
    <pb n="6"/>
    <p> because of this note</p>
</body>
```

On this I apply your for-each-group statement. It produced following output

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>Some random text is put here</p>
                    <p>Another
paragraph starts here, and in the 
middle of it</p>
                </td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p> a page break occurred.</p>
                </td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>the next paragraph begins
on a new page</p>
                    <p>But in the next paragraph, after</p>
                </td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>another page break, something else
 happend : a note
                        <note type="glossary">the note content</note> and so everything
 failing </p>
                    <note type="glossary">the note content</note>
                </td>
                <td>5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p> because of this note</p>
                </td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow !! Thanks a lot for this very elegant solution ! I learnt a lot just studying how you proceed. Really, thanks A LOT !

Comment: However, there's still a problem. I edited the XML file of my example : is there a way to resolve that ?

Comment: Aah, I was afraid of something like this :-) I improved my answer a bit - hope it will work for you.

Comment: So clever ! I think I understood what you've done, but between understanding and doing it, there's quite a gap. Thank you SO MUCH ! 
Don't you think, however, that there's a problem with XSL and milestones tag ? I'm a complete beginner, but it seems to me that XSL was thought really for a :
<staff>
    <employee>
…
</staff>
case. But XML is not only trees ! When encoding a book, a paragraph can begin on one page, and finish on another one --> flat… That's what milestones are for, and XSL doesn't deal well with milestones. You have to "trick" it… am I wrong ? (I hope so !)