# XSLT 2.0 outputting html list based on content between self-closing elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

In my XML document I have encodings of milestones in a text, encoded with a self-closing element `<milestone n="1"/>`. Thus, a text like so:

```
 <p>
   <seg><milestone n="1"/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
    elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt <milestone n="2"/>ut labore
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut <quote>enim <note>ad</note></quote> minim <milestone n="3"/>veniam, 
    quis nostrud exercitation <milestone n="4"/>ullamco laboris nisi 
    ut aliquip ex ea commodo</seg>
   <seg>consequat. Duis aute irure dolor 
    <milestone n="5"/> in reprehenderit <quote>in</quote> voluptate velit esse cillum 
    dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</seg>
 </p>
```

With XSLT 2.0 I am trying to target an HTML output, where all content between each `<milestone/>` is put into an `li` HTML element, ignoring the `<seg>` structure, but allowing for further processing over other nodes:

```
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</li>
<li>ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim</li>
<li>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</li>
<li>ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor</li>
<li>in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</li>
```

The example (below based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618249/xsl-display-text-between-two-milestone-show-milestone-value-elsewhere) and [this](https://wiki.tei-c.org/index.php/MilestoneXSLT)) did not function...

```
<xsl:template match="p" mode="diplo">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="milestone">
            <li>
                <xsl:sequence select="current()/ancestor::p//milestone/@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[not(self::milestone)]"/>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

EDIT: I've updated the XML source to be more clear (I don't want just text, but all nodes for further processing with apply templates), and posted a failed attempt.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think from the `p` elements you would need to group the descendant nodes as the `milestone` are not child nodes of the `p` element, so https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHUf shows that and works to output the `li` items. For the rest you need to be more specific which nodes you want to process and transforrm to which output as it is not clear directly and not that simple once you have processed all descendants at different levels to then proceed with the document structure or other structure.

Comment: I noticed you've used XSLT 3.0, not 2.0...

Comment: That is true as that tool uses Saxon 9.8 which is an XSLT 3 processor but the sample with your input snippet and the relevant code gives the same result with an XSLT 2 processor http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/bFDb2BK

Comment: Because of eXist I am restricted to XSLT 2.0 for the moment...until eXist 5 is production ready. It's frustrating because I learned  XSLT with 3.0 .

Comment: I understand and saw the XSLT 2.0 tag but as I said, the suggestion with the grouping is XSLT 2 compatible, grouping nodes with `for-each-group group-starting-with` has not in any way changed between XSLT 2 and 3 (well, unless we talk about streaming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `for-each-group` and `@group-starting-with` like below:

**XSLT 2.0:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <p>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="seg/node()" group-starting-with="milestone">
                <xsl:sort select="@n"/>
                <li>
                    <!--<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(string-join(current-group(),' '))"/>-->
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[not(self::milestone)]"/>
                </li>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="quote">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text> <!--output contents of <quote> in " " -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="note">
        <xsl:text>[</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:text>]</xsl:text> <!--output contents of <note> in [ ] -->
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**INPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p>
   <seg><milestone n="1"/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
    elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt <milestone n="2"/>ut labore
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut <quote>enim <note>ad</note></quote> minim <milestone n="3"/>veniam, 
    quis nostrud exercitation <milestone n="4"/>ullamco laboris nisi 
    ut aliquip ex ea commodo</seg>
   <seg>consequat. Duis aute irure dolor 
    <milestone n="5"/> in reprehenderit <quote>in</quote> voluptate velit esse cillum 
    dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</seg>
 </p>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
    elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt </li>
   <li>ut labore
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut "enim [ad]" minim </li>
   <li>veniam, 
    quis nostrud exercitation </li>
   <li>ullamco laboris nisi 
    ut aliquip ex ea commodoconsequat. Duis aute irure dolor 
    </li>
   <li> in reprehenderit "in" voluptate velit esse cillum 
    dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</li>
</p>
```

Comment: See mentioned link with modified XSLT: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2D6

Comment: Thanks, but this does not address the question correctly. The output should NOT be text (`value-of`), but should allow further processing through `apply-templates`. See where i wrote "but allowing for further processing over other nodes."

Comment: Do you mean all nodes as well? Then use copy-of instead of value-of.

Comment: Taking your example, I've removed the unnecessary sort but added two templates to transform `<quote>` and `<note>`. Yet these templates do not fire off: http://xsltransform.net/jxN8Nr3/3

Comment: Now you need to `xsl:apply-templates` and one more thing i observed in your newly created template `<apply-template>` should be `<xsl:apply-templates>` see here in mentioned link:  http://xsltransform.net/jxN8Nr3/4

Comment: That's sounds.  Answer Updated.

Comment: @jbrehr Please accept answer if it's really helps you. Thank you.